# I'm not able to ping my printer ip address from computer,Why?

Tags: windows-7

I have a printer connected to my wireless router, however when trying to ping the printer ip address from my computer which is on the same network,Reply comes from computer ip address and it says "Destination host unreachable"

Comment: How about providing more info? Network settings would be a start.

Comment: Is the printer working otherwise? Is it reachable from other machines? How did you determine the printer's IP address?

Comment: Check your gateway.  Make sure it is the same for both your printer and your computer.